# Route tracking on Google map PHP

Tags: google-maps, spatial-database, php, mysql, route

I have to make a software that tracks a vehicle on Google maps using GPS. I have almost done this project but am stuck at a point. The client requires a system that tracks the bus in a route. I am done with the route but how can I track if the vehicle is on the route or out of route?  I looked for a few examples like post GIS or spatial Index on MYSQL but don't know where to start.

In MYSQL I create a linestring, my database structure is:

Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra
id,int(11),NO,PRI,NULL,auto_increment
route_name,varchar(45),YES,,NULL,
from_id,varchar(45),YES,,NULL,
to_id,varchar(45),YES,,NULL,
line_string,geometry,NO,MUL,NULL,

Where a line_string column is geometric column where I am storing all route coordinates now I have a lat long which is located on this line or not have to calculate this.